# compound rate interest with regular monthly deposits formular in php

Tags: php, math, calculator

So im trying to write a compound interest rate formula in php, I have this but its not working, any idea ?

```
<?php

$p = 0;
$pmt = 200;
$r = 0.06;
$t = 3/12;
$n = 12;

$ans = $pmt * (((1 + $r / $n) ^ $n ($t) - 1) / ($r / $n));

echo $ans;
```

so I have tried it in a sandbox and i keep getting function name must be a string
see
https://3v4l.org/rdiJ7

Comment: **HOW** is it "not working" ?

Comment: Il update my question

Comment: Try `$ans = $pmt * ((1+( $r / $n)) ^ ($r * $n));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off that error, if you look at what you've got, you can spot the error by spacing things out:

```
$ans = $pmt *  //All good
(((1 + $r / $n) //An extra bracket to start with that is not closed
 ^ //All good
$n ($t) //No operator here. 
- 1) //All good
/ ($r / $n));
```

So change it to

```
$ans = $pmt * ((1 + $r / $n) ^ ($n * $t - 1) / ($r / $n));
```

You needed an operator between `$n` and `$t`.

**UPDATE**

So

```
P = 0 // start amount
pmt = 200 // monthly deposit
r = 0.06 // Interest amount(6%)
t = 1 // time being 1 year
n = 3/12 // investment after 3 months

ans = 606.02  ?
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, the formula I am trying to work though includes monthly deposits

Comment: Ahh, give me a minute

Comment: thanks Matt, been working on this for a long time now

Comment: Take a look at the new answer.

Comment: @Beep Updated it again, there was also an additional bracket.

Comment: have updated your answer with the answer providing i put in certain variables